# Generate Private Key with AES 256 CTR

Tags: aes, ssh

How to generate a private key with AES 256-CTR ? I need a private key with CTR as CBC is no longer supported by my client. Please advise

### Details:

We need to connect to an SFTP instance of client using a .ppk file. This file will contain algo when we generate that using puttygen. 
Ex:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,6C3E08378BC131E1C99A6A70044DC9D0 -------------
```

Now the problem is SFTP instance of client is not using CBC any more. They are asking us to generate a ppk file with AES-128-CTR/AES-256-CTR. Is there any other way where i can generate this ? I have tried using powershell with openssh as well. But, still i am getting key with AES-128-CBC.

Comment: Using puttygen. But, it is giving a default one as CBC.

Comment: We need to connect to an SFTP instance of client using a .ppk file. This file will contain algo when we generate that using puttygen. 
Ex: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,6C3E08378BC131E1C99A6A70044DC9D0
-------------
Now the problem is SFTP instance of client is not using CBC any more. 
They are asking us to generate a ppk file with AES-128-CTR/AES-256-CTR. 
Is there any other way where i can generate this ? 
I have tried using powershell with openssh.. But, still i am getting key with AES-128-CBC.

Comment: By 'SFTP instance of client' do you actually mean an SFTP _server_ belonging to someone else and you are failing to connect to that server with a _client program_? The example you show is **OpenSSL-and-OpenSSH format NOT ppk** plus ppk ONLY supports aes256-cbc encryption -- but ssh connection is completely unaffected by any local keyfile encryption. Are you sure they don't want you to use aes(N)-ctr from rfc4344 as the **data cipher for the connection**? That would make a lot more sense, as SSH2's use of cbc has the same 'chaining' vulnerability as SSL3/TLS1.0 did.